# wordpress permalinks for custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm using tribe events in wordpress and been struggling with the following problem:

I have events (custom post type) filtered by category (default taxonomy for this plugin).
I'm using "pretty permalinks settings" so my url looks like that:
[website.com]/events/category/Amsterdam/ (when my category is Amsterdam).

And now to the question:
I sub filtered my posts by another custom taxonomy called “event_type” (concert, pub …)
when I'm trying to get all the posts from Amsterdam that are a "concert" type, my url is:
[website.com]/events/category/amsterdam/?event_type=concert
on default permalink settings the url is:
[website.com]/index.php?tribe_events_cat=amsterdam&event_type=concert

How do I get WordPress to transform and to recognize my url as:
[website.com]/events/category/amsterdam/event_type/concert/

I know it has something to do with the rewrite_rules_array but could not manage to do so.
Any help would be very appreciated!

Thanx in advance.

Comment: You may have better luck posting this question over on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

While You register custom post type:

```
function people_init() {
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'people',
        'post',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'People' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'person' ),
            'capabilities' => array(
                'assign_terms' => 'edit_guides',
                'edit_terms' => 'publish_guides'
            )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'people_init' );
```

checkout the "rewrite" parameter. More You can check here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Also sometimes You need to flush permalink structure by going to permalink settings and clicking save (dont ask me why) ;).

Comment: Thanx for your reply, but it doesnt do the trick.
I have a rewrite rule for this taxonomy, so the taxonomy page looks ok:
[website.com]/event_type/concert/
The problem is when i add a secondary taxonomy filter under another taxonomy page. and then my url doesn't get rewritten as follow:
[website.com]/events/category/amsterdam/?event_type=concert
any other suggestion?